# Convert .ttf or .otf to .woff in front-end javascript

Tags: javascript, fonts, truetype, opentype, woff

My clients upload their fonts in my website, and I would like to convert all of them (especially `.otf` and `.ttf`) to `.woff` from the navigator (JS). I have been looking for a tool doing such thing but I couldn't find any, do you know something ?

Comment: why? Presumably the uploads go to your server, so verify-and-convert them on the server and then return the location of that new asset as your "upload succeeded" status. Don't do in the browser what you can already do better on the server.

Comment: I can't have a server, that's part of the requirements from my client : server is just a DB, nothing more

Comment: It sounds like a realistic and perfect solution here is to simply tell your clients to upload .woff themselves. Woff and Woff2 require deflate/brotli encoding, which requires huge-for-browser libraries, you're not going to embed those in a bundle.